# Monodroid Development Issue for Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 - Android Layout Design Canvas Issues

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

I am getting an error on all my Android Layouts in my Android Solutions (Mono for Android) for both `Visual Studio 2012` and `MonoDevelop` on my Windows 8 machine.
I was **not** getting this error message in`Visual Studio 2010` and `MonoDevelop` on my Windows 7 machine.

I have tried creating a new solution in both VS 2012 and MonoDevelop and I still get the following error on default Android Layout in Android Solutions (Mono for Android). Regardless of error on Design Canvas, I am able to edit the source code for the Android Layout, as well as build and deploy app without errors.

The **error message** is as follows:

> "The layout could not be loaded: Could not find bool resource matching value 0x11100009 (resolved name: config_ui_enableFadingMarquee) in current configuration."

Please let me know if you have an idea of what maybe causing this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Resource/Layout and click on the Main.axml

You should open it without any problems. If you need to add more layout pages this is where you place them. I hope I was helpful.